# External monitor makes default screen turn off

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, suspend

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 and once in a while I have a problem with my dual monitor setup. Sometimes, after I try to wake my computer up from suspend I cannot get both monitors working. If I plug any external monitor, the default screen in my laptop goes completely black. I tried to turn it on via settings->displays, but no success. If I unplug it, the default screen is working fine again.
These are the output of xrandr command when external monitor is plugged in:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1600x900      60.11 +
   ...

DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   ...
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-2 disconnected
```

After I unplugged it the output looks like this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1600x900      60.11*+
   ...
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-2 disconnected
```

Another strange behaviour of that state is that when no external monitor is plugged in my laptop automatically suspends after a while (a minute or sometimes even less).

These issues disappear after reboot.

Could someone help me with this problem and suggest what can be done to solve it?